# Angular to Spring Boot Micro services connectivity Error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am trying to connect from my Angular application to the back end micro-services built on Spring Boot and Spring Cloud.
UI calls the microservices layer through Zuul which routes to the respective microservice

I am getting the below error while connecting to microservices from the angular UI in the browser console:

Failed to load: https://microservice url - Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Can some one please explain what this error refers to?

Comment: Typical CORS issue. Google it there is much on that topic.

Comment: See: http://dontpanic.42.nl/2015/04/cors-with-spring-mvc.html and make sure you include the `OPTIONS` method.

Comment: Your API doesn't allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. You'll have to either whitelist the requesting domain, or use JSONP(would only work if GET was intended but JSONP is also supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem i implemented the interface  Filter

And then allow **Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Expose-Headers**
to added CORS issue

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{


 @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");


            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            logger.info(request.getRemoteAddr());
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the above CORS Filter worked for me with few additional changes. 1. We are using few custom headers which is part of the Access-Control-Request-Headers, adding the same headers in Access-Control-Allow-Headers 2. Adding the @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) to the CORS Filter